# Specifying time duration for query?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I want to create a dashboard that shows me how many clicks I had today vs how many clicks I had on the exact same day last week.

From the docs, the diffSeries function can subtract a series from another but how do I get the timeseries of previous week?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you need [timeShift](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.timeShift) function.